# Removing certain word in file name

Tags: powershell, file-rename, get-childitem

I would like to remove the word “.pdf” in the file name. It’s not the extension of the file as I named it with “.pdf” previously. How do I remove it on all of the files? My files are located in many folders within the main folder.

> C:\MainFolder\Folder1\document.pdf
>
> C:\MainFolder\Folder2\document
>
> C:\MainFolder\Folder3\document.pdf

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Replace(“.pdf”,””) + $_.Extension }
```

I tried using this but it only removes in the folder itself. I need to do it for all of the folders

Comment: I have not seen your piece of code and the folder structure and sample file names. Please edit the question and share the same. Also, based on my assumption, I am giving an answer.

Comment: Please do not delete and re-post the exact same question. Edit and improve your existing question to avoid loosing all clarification already discussed in the comments.

Comment: Just add the `-Recurse` option to [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) to scan all subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
    $files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\mypath' -Recurse

    foreach( $file in $files ) {

    if( !$file.PSIsContainer ) {

        $extension = $file.Extension
        $newname   = $file.BaseName.Replace('.pdf', '' ) + $extension
        Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $newname | Out-Null
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need foreach loop here. Rename-item can technically rename all in a single shot.

Comment: It did not work. The file has still the word “.pdf” in it.

Comment: I've tested it here. "test.pdf.txt" becomes "test.txt". Is this what you want?

Comment: It loses its extension. It was a PDF file

Comment: Not here. "test.pdf" stays "test.pdf". What is the name of your file?

Comment: Img038374.pdf is the file name

Comment: When I run my script "Img038374.pdf" stays "Img038374.pdf". What should be the expected name?

Comment: It should be Img038374 as I have hide extension for known files

Comment: Ah, you want to remove ".pdf" from ALL files. I've updated my script accordingly, try this.

Comment: It completely remove the extension too. I’m unable to open up the file. I’m sorry for the confusion. The file name is “image123.pdf”.  I have hide extension for known files. If I uncheck it, it would be “image123.pdf.pdf”. I would like to change the name to “image123” with hide extension checked in the folder options

Comment: Ah, we get closer. :) Have a look on my updated script, this should do it.

Comment: I got it working! Thank you very much!! If I want to remove a certain word for my folders. What should I do?

Comment: Create a new question and give an example pls.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your piece of code with this:

```
#Finds all files with the string “pdf” anywhere in the name recursively and will replace with nothing(which will remove basically).
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\your\root\folder\path -Filter "*pdf*" -Recurse  | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "pdf",''}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This would remove the extension from pdf files as well.

Comment: So pick the extension and after removing add it back. :)

Comment: Or change the replace statement to `-replace '.pdf.pdf' to '.pdf'`

Comment: @PaulG: If it is not pdf then that might cause an issue. But if it is only pdf then yes we are good with it.

Answer (score 0):

As [Filburt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205233/filburt) points out in a comment on the question, **the only thing missing from your command is the `-Recurse` switch** in order to process files in the entire directory subtree of the input path.

Additionally, to be safe, **add the `-File` switch in order to limit processing to *files*** (and not also directories):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Replace('.pdf', '') + $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

<sup>The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) *previews* the operation. Remove it once you're sure it will do what you want.</sup>

Note that files whose base names do not contain the substring `.pdf` are effectively ignored.

To speed up processing, you could make `Get-ChildItem` preselect the files of interest with 
`-Filter *.pdf?*`